# It is possible to change packages installation directory for Package Manager Console?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, nuget

I'm using nuget integration with msbuild (visual studio 2012) to automatically restore broken packages. Below you can see my .nuget/nuget.config file for solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <disabledPackageSources />
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="..\..\Lib\NuGet\Packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

My packages directory moved outside from solution. This works fine during build, but Package Manager Console still using `$(SolutionDir)\packages` to install (and restore) packages.

It is possible to change packages directory for "Package Manager Console"?

Answer (score 0):

nuget.config

You got the first part:

```
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="..\MySuperCoolPackages" />
  </config>
```

But you have to tell the command line about the nuget.config file explicitly.

```
C:\SomeFolder\NuGet.exe install "C:\MySolution\.nuget\packages.config" -ConfigFile "C:\MySolution\.nuget\nuget.config"
```

Comment: Yes, the command line tool nees to specify "ConfigFile" parameter, but the problem in fact with Package manager console - this is another tool (based on PowerShell afaik).

Answer (score 0):

When you create nuget.config with repositoryPath you need to restart VS for it to be reread and console to be aware of it.

Edit: @DmitryBykadorov weird, may be your nuget is out of date? There was an early problem where due to config being in `.nuget` subfolder and not in `.csproj`'s current>parent>parent>etc path it wouldn't see it and required one `nuget.config` with restore info and one (typically next to .sln or .csproj itself) with `repositoryPath`, but my VS2012 with whatever latest nuget it comes with works fine with config below. May be your global nuget config somehow affects it, or your solution needs hard clean/rebuild?

```
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="..\..\lib" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

Comment: No, restart did not helps.

Comment: sorry for delay. Another questions appears here: 1) how to check nuget version and which version have described problem? 2) afaik global nuget config always created in user directory, but in my case I want to override them by local config 3) I have similar config but it not affected to the manager console (but affected on msbuild)